# android external/stlport include in Android.mk build not successfull

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-ndk-r5, android-source

I m trying to build an app with android-froyo source in which I am using `skia` and `stl` templates,

I have included

```
MY_INCLUDES=external/zlib external/jpeg external/freetype/include \
    frameworks/base/core/jni/android/graphics  external/skia/include/core \
    external/libpng external/expat/lib <b>external/stlport/stlport</b>

libstlport_cflags := -D_GNU_SOURCE
libstlport_cppflags := -fuse-cxa-atexit 

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := $(libstlport_cppflags)
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

I get the following error when i try to build the android source with this app, which i kept at packages/apps:

> external/stlport/stlport/stl/_new.h:47:50: error: libstdc++/include/new: No such file or directory

Please guide me to rectify this issue.

Thanks

Mohit

Comment: I tried added LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARY := libstlport as well, but it doesn't even include stl files

Comment: I took the liberty to re-format your post. StackOverflow (SO) uses the awesome `Markdown` library for post markup. It's really worth looking into :) Oh... and welcome to SO! ;)

Answer (score 7):

As I understand the file which cannot be found by preprocessor is located in `bionic` folder.

I had the same issue and I solved it by adding the following line:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += bionic
```

Comment: This is the answer. Bionic contains the Android-flavored standard libraries.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this with Android 2.2 but I'm using Android Kitkat (4.4).

To get the `stlport` library working with our project we included it in ***our project's `Android.mk`*** as so:

```
include external/stlport/libstlport.mk
```

This is assuming that on Froyo, there is a libstlport.mk file to include in your build process. In 4.4, there is also a Android.mk file but that builds other code as well and builds stlport as a static library (which is not what we wanted).

You may need to also add the include directory as well, something like: `external/stlport/stlport`.

Comment: `include external/stlport/libstlport.mk` helped also for Android 4.2.2, but I also need to add `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libstlport`.

Answer (score 1):

```
cpp
#include <stdio.h>
// The code 
// The set of definitions and includes for STLPort 
// They used defined() instead of #ifdef. 
#define _STLP_HAS_INCLUDE_NEXT  1 
#define _STLP_USE_MALLOC   1 
#define _STLP_USE_NO_IOSTREAMS  1 
#include <stl/config/_android.h> 
#include <map>
#include <string> 

int main(void)
{
    std::string a = "abc";
    printf("%s",a.c_str());
    return 0;
}

Android.mk
# A simple test for the minimal standard C++ library
#
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test-libstl.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libstlport 
LOCAL_MODULE := test-libstl
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Comment: Hi friends, I am compiling Android 4.0, during this I got an error  : "external/stlport/stlport/stl/_iterator_base.h:116:43: error: libstdc++/include/iterator: No such file or directory
". any one have idea on this.