# fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory

Tags: android, c++

I m creating a system app in android.
As I want to use some hardware permissions, I have to make it as a system app.

In my app, I m using lots of native codes, containing both c sources and cpp sources.

The problem is with cpp sources file.

I m getting the following error while compiling a .cpp file

```
fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
```

I am using the mm command for building. How to make use of the cpp features in this android build ?

Comment: These could be related to the same problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721856/unable-to-include-iostream-in-android-why

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130429/android-ndk-build-iostream-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: I have the same error..the error is that the name of file was wrong which i have send..you should also check the file name

Comment: @Andrea, this is not the same problem, this is a system app,,, and if i am building as a normal user app, there is no problem as I have the application.mk files as mentioned in ur link,, this is coming only when i am building it as a system app..

Comment: @jyomin, this not about the filename... I checked, it is trying to compile a file, and in that file only i m adding #include <iostream> which the compiler is not able to find

Comment: @jithin: Sorry, I just thinked that the issues were the same. Since you solved, you can mark your own answer as the correct one. :-D

Comment: In my case (Android 4.2.2, system app) this helped http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650672/android-external-stlport-include-in-android-mk-build-not-successfull/25937823#25937823

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the problem, not sure why.

LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cxx .cpp .cc

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES +=  libstlport

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += external/stlport/stlport 
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += bionic
```